# Visual Studio 2019: Error CS0012 with NetStandard

Tags: xml, nuget, .net-standard

I'm very new to software development and am trying to get some web software to run and we can't figure out what's causing this issue. We are getting the following error:

`CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[not sure if I should share this]'.`

We tried installing version 2.0.0.0 of netstandard.library onto VS, but it isn't showing up in the solution explorer and it isn't changing the error message. We have cleared the bin and obj folders and stopped and restarted VS but the same error message keeps appearing. Any insight as to why this could be happening would be very greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!